# do i need to add service reference to consume RESTFul service?

Tags: asp.net, json, rest, service

I am completely new to the whole web service concept but I have gone through some of the beginner vids at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx.

I am working on a asp.net web project that will consume a service (apparently restful) which returns data in json format.

As I mentioned before, I've already gone through the "create 1st web service/client" videos from the aforementioned site and felt I had a good grasp on the concept. However, now that I'm getting to work on the project my colleague insists that there is no need to add a service reference for a restful service. Is this true?

Also, if anyone could give me REALLY good advice/guidance for this task you'd get 50 thousand cool points (cool points not redeemable anywhere)!

---

thanks all, after more searching i found the resolution i needed at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233698/Consuming-a-Json-WebService-from-a-Csharp-or-VB-Ap

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have experience with RESTful but I do use SOAP. You can add a service reference quite easily if your client is in .Net. But no you don't have to add a service reference. If you know the structure of the request you can use simple http.

Might not be enough advice for the 50,000 cool points but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to add a service reference to a RESTful service, if you use something like jQuery, some other JavaScript library or do everything yourself in plain old JavaScript. But you can create a service reference and use the generadted proxy client if you like. It really depends on what you want or need to do.

Here is a link to a [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call) project you might want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to, but you can. Why would you? So that you get automatic object serialization and deserialization. I haD a client for whom I always generated a test client, with the service reference, to save time - but then they ultimately consumed it with a PHP client, which definitely didn't have a service reference.

If the call is simple enough, you can call it directly in the browser. I always implemented a GetVersion call like that to test that the service was working on a basic level.

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague might be referring to the use of MVC Controllers to deliver JSON content via AJAX calls from your client end. In this case there is no external .dll's that are necessary.

MVC Scaffolding makes a RESTful type interface very easy to setup. Here is one possible way how you would do it.

```
public class HomeController : AsynController
{
     [HttpPost] //Create
     public JsonResult CreateStuff(Stuff s)
     {
         var newStuff = new Stuff { Property = s.Property };
         db.Stuff.Add(newStuff);
         db.SaveChanges();
         return Json(new { data = newStuff }, JsonBehavior.AllowGetRequest);
     }

     [HttpGet] //Read
     public JsonResult GetStuff(int id)
     {
         var stuff = db.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();           
         return Json(new { data = stuff }); //Check for null on the js side.
     }

     [HttpPut] //Update
     public JsonResult UpdateStuff(Stuff s)
     { 
         bool updated = false;
         var stuff = db.Where(x => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
         if (stuff != null)
             updated = true;
             stuff.Property = s.Property;

         return Json(new { data = stuff, updated = updated});
     }


     [HttpDelete] //delete
     public JsonResult DeleteStuff(int id)
     {
         bool deleted = false;
         var deleteThis = db.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

          if (deleteThis != null)              
              db.Stuff.Remove(deleteThis);
              db.SaveChanges();
              deleted = true;

         return Json(new { deleted = deleted });
     }

}
 //js side
 //more sophisticated logic goes here
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({ url : '/CreateStuff/', 
                success : function(e) { 
                              console.log("created " + e); 
                 }
               });
      });
```